# Is it possible to redirect raw input to a specific window?

Tags: windows, winapi, input, keyboard

I have a Windows Media Center remote that windows recognizes as a keyboard. When I run a multi-monitor setup with Windows Media Center playing a video on one screen, the remote's input is directed to the active window along with the regular keyboard. So when I'm doing something on the other screen, Windows Media Center doesn't respond to the remote. I thought I'd write a simple low level keyboard hook that traps all key events, determines which presses came from the remote, and redirects those to the open Media Center window.

I found out in [Is it possible to determine which keyboard sent a keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149796/is-it-possible-to-determine-which-keyboard-sent-a-keypress) that I need to use raw input functions to determine which keyboard sent each key event.  Now that I have this, I was going to add a low level keyboard hook which checked the information from the raw input, but Windows apparently does not allow you to run both a low level hook and receive raw input simultaneously.

I happen to fit into the one case they excluded: I need raw input to determine the keyboard, and I could really use a hook in order to block and resend the key events that need to be redirected.

So, short of running two processes to get both abilities, is there a way to block/redirect input from raw input to a specific open window?

EDIT: I've tried separate threads.  No go.

Comment: You should first check out [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/how-do-i-send-key-strokes-to-a-window-without-having-to-activate-it-using-window)

Comment: Could also briefly activate it, I suppose.  I'll have to see what happens when I get that far.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I'm having almost the same problem..

Comment: No. I doubt anything has changed, but just in case I might try again. Best guess from what I saw last time, you'll need to create two processes to work together through some dubious means.